# Remove column cotext menu from angular grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am using angular grid ui-grid 3.0.I have to remove column context menu icon from this please solve my issue 
[image: refer image for issue]

Comment: A demo or even any code would be helpful.

Comment: is their any property which i have to set?

Comment: <div ng-controller="TestController">
    <div id="grid1" ui-grid="{ data: myData }" class="grid"></div>
</div>

Comment: Can you make a demo over [here](http://plnkr.co/edit), after you've done that I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the configuration option avaialble in `ui-grid`. You can configure most of your grid options from there.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/wiki/configuration-options

You can set `groupingShowAggregationMenu: false` to hide it from the grid.